# Placement of multiple columns in multiple indices with multind and svmono.cls

Tags: sectioning, indexing, subdividing, sv-classes

I'm trying to implement multiple indices in my LaTeX file. I have to use the style file of Springer (`svmono.cls`; -> [Link to zipped Springer Style](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/svmono.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-491898-0)) and did the indices with the package `multind`.

Indexing went smoothly, but they wouldn't be generated as chapters. I tried to change that by altering the following line in the `multind.sty` file: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}% chapter instead of section`.

Now the indices were chapters, but the headings wouldn't be in the general style of the LaTeX file. Here I got this code from a guy, which worked quite nicely:

```
\makeatletter
\def\printindex#1#2{
\chapter*{#2}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
\@input{#1.ind}}

\makeatother
```

Well...the headings look right now. But the index is generated with in one column instead of two, which is the way it was before (and the way I want it!).

So I tried to use the package `multicol`. It works in that I have the index in two colums, but in the beginning of the chapter, the second colums is not positioned the right way. I made a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Link to the Screenshot]

So...what do I do now to adjust the right column? On the next page the colums are aligned, but then there's no chapter beginning there (but the heading).

I hope that my question is comprehensible, as I'm rather new to LaTeX and not a native speaker. Thanks in advance for any help :).

P.S.: I also tried to create a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{svmono} % Style-file vom Springer Verlag
\usepackage{multicol} % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Neue deutsche Rechtschreibung und Trennmuster
\usepackage{multind} % Für mehrere Indizes

\makeatletter
\def\printindex#1#2{
\chapter*{#2}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline {\arabic{chapter}}#2}
\@input{#1.ind}}

\makeatother

\makeindex{index} % Wird zur Erstellung der Indizes verwendet
\makeindex{autorenregister} % makeindex / (sprmidx.sty)

\begin{document}

\title{Wurst}
\date{}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Kapitel 1}
Test.
\chapter{Testbla}
blablabla

\backmatter
\printindex{autorenregister}{Autorenregister}
\printindex{index}{Index}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the `amsbook.cls` creates a two-column index based on `\chapter*`.  you might be able to adapt it to the style required by `svmono`.  (really, i'm surprised that springer doesn't have any facility in its monograph class for a two-column index.  look into the `.cls` file and see if there is a command `\printindex`.)

Answer (score 3):

If you use `imakeidx` instead of `multind` all should go as you wish:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx} % Für mehrere Indizes

\makeindex[name=index,title=Index,options=-s svind.ist]
\makeindex[name=autorenregister,title=Autorenregister,options=-s svind.ist]
```

In the document, index entries should be like

```
\index[index]{Entry}
\index[autorenregister]{Autor}
```

(the optional argument decides in what index the entry should be placed). In order to print the indices, write

```
\printindex[autorenregister]
\printindex[index]
```

Comment: Sorry to disturb, can you advise if the usage of `mulltind.sty` is wrong? Should we use either `imakeidx` or `splitindex` instead of `multind`? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi It's not wrong; but there are packages that do better.